# Xcode Errors with my app

Tags: xcode

My app downloaded onto my iPhone successfully, but when I tap on it, the app closes almost immediately when it pops up.
This error occurs when I build the app:

> /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-gjmiflxpbqhnrhdimckrauaacamp/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Script-033966F41B18B03000ECD701.sh:
>   line 2: /Users/camerongenao/Downloads/IITSEC-2/MapFileParser.sh:
>   Permission denied

Comment: Check this link-> https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/command-bin-sh-failed-with-exit-code-126-xcode-build-failed.382200/ BTW looks like the script's address is not dynamically set. (users/.../downloads or deriveddata is on your computer. these files should be added with referenced address.

Comment: What is your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command man chmod for more details about chmod, but you should be able to run this command on the OSX machine:

```
chmod a+x /path/to/MapFileParser.sh
```

dont forget to restart X code again as well "a+x"..

It works for me.......